# TF.data.dataset.map(map_func) with Eager Mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, eager

I am using TF 1.8 with eager mode enabled.

I cannot print the example inside the mapfunc. It when I run tf.executing_eagerly() from within the mapfunc I get "False"

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

tfe = tf.contrib.eager
tf.enable_eager_execution()
x = tf.random_uniform([16,10], -10, 0, tf.int64)
print(x)
DS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x))


def mapfunc(ex, con):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    new_ex = ex + con
    print(new_ex) 
    return new_ex

DS = DS.map(lambda x: mapfunc(x, [7]))
DS = DS.make_one_shot_iterator()

print(DS.next())
```

print(new_ex) outputs:

```
Tensor("add:0", shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
```

Outside mapfunc, it works fine. But inside it, the passed example does not have a value, nor .numpy() attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tf.data` transformations actually execute as a graph, so the body of the map function itself isn't executed eagerly. See [#14732](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14732#issuecomment-347276740) for some more discussion on this.

If you really need eager execution for the map function, you could use [`tf.contrib.eager.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/py_func), so something like:

```
DS = DS.map(lambda x: tf.contrib.eager.py_func(
  mapfunc,
  [x, tf.constant(7, dtype=tf.int64)], tf.int64)
# In TF 1.9+, the next line can be print(next(DS))
print(DS.make_one_shot_iterator().next())
```

Hope that helps.

Note that by adding a `py_func` to the dataset, the single-threaded Python interpreter will be in the loop for every element produced.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am going for the performance optimization techniques that were advertised during the Dev Summit '18. I am using this for text, and also using it to pass different preprocessing functions in a more elegant way.

Comment: Another thing that I just noticed: in the arguments' list, you can only pass tensors, but not general objects, such as another function. In my case, I would want to pass a tokenizer since I am working with text, but anyway this is still doable in the **mapfunc** function's body.

Answer (score 3):

Anything within map is run as graph no matter what mode is used outside. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map

As in the page, there are 3 options:

> 1. Rely on AutoGraph to convert Python code into an equivalent graph computation. The downside of this approach is that AutoGraph can convert some but not all Python code.
> 2. Use **tf.py_function**, which allows you to write arbitrary Python code but will generally result in worse performance than 1)
> 3. Use **tf.numpy_function**, which also allows you to write arbitrary Python code. Note that tf.py_function accepts tf.Tensor whereas tf.numpy_function accepts numpy arrays and returns only numpy arrays.

With tf.py_function() your line will become:

```
DS = DS.map(lambda y: tf.py_function(
                          (lambda x: mapfunc(x, [7])),
                          inp=[y], Tout=tf.int64
                      ))
```

The same applies to tf.map_fn() and tf.vectorized_map().