# Efficient way to preprocess data for DETR model (object detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, tf.keras

```py
import keras_core as keras # so that i can use keras_cv
import keras_cv
from keras_cv import bounding_box
from keras_cv import visualization
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

def visualize_dataset(inputs, value_range, rows, cols, bounding_box_format):
    inputs = next(iter(inputs.take(1)))
    images, bounding_boxes = inputs["images"], inputs["bounding_boxes"]
    visualization.plot_bounding_box_gallery(
        images,
        value_range=value_range,
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        y_true=bounding_boxes,
        scale=5,
        font_scale=0.7,
        bounding_box_format=bounding_box_format,
        class_mapping=class_mapping,
    )


def unpackage_raw_tfds_inputs(inputs, bounding_box_format):
  image = inputs["image"]
  boxes = keras_cv.bounding_box.convert_format(
      inputs["objects"]["bbox"],
      images=image,
      source="rel_yxyx",
      target=bounding_box_format,
  )
  bounding_boxes = {
      "classes": tf.cast(inputs["objects"]["label"] + 1, dtype=tf.float32),
      "boxes": tf.cast(boxes, dtype=tf.float32),
  }
  return {"images": tf.cast(image, tf.float32), "bounding_boxes": bounding_boxes}

def load_pascal_voc(split, dataset, bounding_box_format):
  ds = tfds.load(dataset, split=split, with_info=False, shuffle_files=True)
  ds = ds.map(lambda x: unpackage_raw_tfds_inputs(x, bounding_box_format=bounding_box_format), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  return ds


train_ds = load_pascal_voc(split="test", dataset="voc/2007", bounding_box_format="xywh"); print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds))
val_ds = load_pascal_voc(split="validation", dataset="voc/2007", bounding_box_format="xywh"); print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds))
test_ds = load_pascal_voc(split="train", dataset="voc/2007", bounding_box_format="xywh"); print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_ds))

# so that I can visualize_dataset
train_ds = train_ds.ragged_batch(1, drop_remainder=True)
val_ds = val_ds.ragged_batch(1, drop_remainder=True)
test_ds = test_ds.ragged_batch(1, drop_remainder=True)
```

Padding the classes and bounding boxes for training [DETR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.12872v3.pdf) model from scratch in tensorflow

```py
def pad(dataset):
  images, classes, boxes = [], [], [] # (m, None, None, 3), (m, 42), (m, 42, 4)

  for x in dataset:
    
    images.append(list(x["images"][0].numpy()))

    classes.append(list(tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(x["bounding_boxes"]["classes"].numpy(), maxlen=42, padding='post')[0]))

    padded_bboxes = np.zeros((1, 42, 4), dtype=np.float32)
    padded_bboxes[: ,:np.shape(x["bounding_boxes"]["boxes"][0])[0], :] = x["bounding_boxes"]["boxes"][0]
    boxes.append(list(padded_bboxes[0]))

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, (classes, boxes)))  
  return dataset
```

Is there any other efficient method to do the above without converting them from `tf.data.Dataset` format to array then again convert to `tf.data.Dataset` format?

I tried to use `.map()` to the datasets but got an error that I can only use `tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences` in eager mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`tf.pad`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) function

```py
train_ds = load_pascal_voc(split="validation", dataset="voc/2007", bounding_box_format="xywh")

N = 42
max_height, max_width = 500, 500
def preprocess(x):
  return keras_cv.layers.Resizing(max_height, max_width, bounding_box_format="xywh", pad_to_aspect_ratio=True)(x["images"]),

 (tf.pad([x["bounding_boxes"]["classes"]], [[0,0], [N,N]])[0][N:-len(x["bounding_boxes"]["classes"])], tf.pad(x["bounding_boxes"]["boxes"], [[N,N], [0,0]])[N:-len(x["bounding_boxes"]["boxes"])])

TRAIN_DS = train_ds.map(lambda x: preprocess(x))

for i in TRAIN_DS.take(2): # test
  print(i[0].numpy().shape)
  print(i[1][0].numpy().shape)
  print(i[1][1].numpy().shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the issue raised [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27811) with the explanation and solution. I was a bit confused at first to see `eager` mode is disabled when by default it is enabled in `tf 2.x`.

I haven't checked this but also check if upgrading `tf` solves the problem or not. I am saying this because, the solution states in future `tf 2.x` may not have this problem.

If you don't need to use the `map` function then your solution is good enough.

**EDIT**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50538038/tf-data-dataset-mapmap-func-with-eager-mode) in stackoverflow. It shows how to enable eager mode execution within the `map()` function.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: my main concern is, will not using `tf.data.Dataset` format to store datasets make it longer for training?

Comment: BTW my question was about using `tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences` in `map()` function to dataset of format`tf.data.Dataset`

Comment: Answer to your first question - It should not. The `tf.data.Dataset` was meant to provide efficient input pipelines especially if the data is large.
Answer to your second question - You cannot use it as inside the `map()` method the eager mode is not enabled (as per the issue I have linked) which will not allow you to run `pad_sequences`.

Comment: And also I have observed storing data in arrays takes up ram while in `tf.data.Dataset` format the ram usage (actually very less compared to arrays) wasn't as much as for the arrays.

Comment: I don't know exactly why that happens, someone with a more in-depth knowledge of the framework maybe able to help you with that. But based on the purpose of the `tf.data.Dataset` API as per the documentation it is meant to be more efficient (both in terms of runtime and space usage) than naïvely using arrays for storing and processing data.

Comment: so if i want `tf.data.Dataset` format for my data (not arrays) how can I proceed (the code using `map()`) if I can't use `tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences` in `map()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254718/discussion-between-vvy-and-tintin98).